# Restrict counter to be between 0 and 10

Tags: javascript, html, function, if-statement

I would like to create 2 buttons one of which increases a number and the other decreases it, and I did do it. The problem is I don't want the numbers to go higher than 10 or lower than 0, I tried if else but didn't work. Can you, please, help me?

Here is the code:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    document.querySelector('#add').onclick = adding
    document.querySelector('#minus').onclick = subtracting
})

let counter = 0
function adding() {
    counter++
    document.querySelector('h1').innerHTML = counter

}


function subtracting() {
    counter--
    document.querySelector('h1').innerHTML = counter
    if( counter < 1){
        document.getElementById('minus').disabled = true
    } else{
        document.getElementById('minus').disabled = false
    }

}
```

Comment: If you assign `let counter = 5` at the start, you'll find that the disabling of your subtraction button _does_ work as expected-- you're on the right track-- you just need to apply the same logic for the `adding` function, and consider where/when you assess what buttons need to be disabled.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you delegate and use booleans in the way they are meant

I disabled the minus on load

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  let counter = 0;
  const plus = document.getElementById('plus');
  const minus = document.getElementById('minus');
  const result = document.querySelector('h1');
  document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    const tgt = e.target;
    counter += tgt.id === "plus" ? 1 : -1; // which one did we click - this can be expanded

    minus.disabled = counter < 1;
    plus.disabled = counter >= 10;

    result.innerHTML = counter;
  })
})
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <button type="button" id="minus" disabled>-</button>
  <h1>0</h1>
  <button type="button" id="plus">+</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is

```
const MAX_COUNTER = 10;
const MIN_COUNTER = 0;
function adding() {
    if (counter < MAX_COUNTER) {
        counter++
        document.querySelector('h1').innerHTML = counter
    }
}
```

Another way is:

```
const MAX_COUNTER = 10;
const MIN_COUNTER = 0;
function adding() {
    counter = Math.min(counter + 1, MAX_COUNTER);
    document.querySelector('h1').innerHTML = counter
}
```

The subtracting is similar.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine. You only need to add another if conditional for adding and put it in the adding function.

```
if( counter >=10){
    document.getElementById('add').disabled = true
} else{
    document.getElementById('add').disabled = false
}
```

Comment: Hi. I had this conditional, still didnt work, then I removed it.

Comment: Please do not use ifs if you have a boolean

Answer (score 0):

I added a working snippet for you, you can create a common function to set the value andenable or disable button based on counter values.

```js
var counter = 0;

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

  //initial value
  setCounterValue(counter);

  //add function
  document.querySelector('#add').onclick = function() {
    setCounterValue(++counter); //increase the counter
  }

  //substract function
  document.querySelector('#minus').onclick = function() {
    setCounterValue(--counter); //decrease the counter
  }
});

//set the value and enable or disable buttons
function setCounterValue(value) {
  document.querySelector('h1').innerHTML = value;
  document.getElementById('minus').disabled = (value <= 0);
  document.getElementById('add').disabled = (value >= 10);
}
```

```html
<p> Counter </p>
<h1 id="h1"> </h1>
<button id="add">Add</button> <button id="minus">Substract</button>
```